# How to collect data though facebook connect and print it in a new page

Tags: facebook, session, printing

It would be great if someone can help me with this.

I am developing a site(ww.xyz.com) in PHP and have successfully integrated the "Login with Facebook" button on the index page of this site. I have tested it and it is working fine.

This site apart from a "Login with Facebook" button also has it's own login form through which already registered users can login to this site. Once the user logs in through this login form(not login with Facebook option) a session is started and the user is taken to another page where his profile details(like first name, last name, email address etc.) are displayed.

Now with the "Login with Facebook" Button I want to do a similar functionality. Where once a user is authenticated via facebook account following two steps should happen.

**Step 1. He or She should be taken to the same page  to which users are taken to if they login via the website's own login form by openning an appropriate session. In this page the users data(like picture, firstname, lastname etc.) should be displayed.
Step**

**Step 2. Collect this data(picture, firstname, lastname etc.) sent by facebook connect and store it in my MYSQL Database.**

For your refernce below is the code for the index.html page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>XYZ Index</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.ptour_crtbtn { BORDER-BOTTOM: #ccc 1px outset; MIN-WIDTH: 100px; TEXT-   
ALIGN:       center; BORDER-LEFT: #ccc 1px outset; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; PADDING-LEFT:  
2px; PADDING-RIGHT: 2px; BACKGROUND: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%; COLOR: 
#fff; BORDER-TOP: #ccc 1px outset; CURSOR: pointer; BORDER-RIGHT: #ccc 1px outset; 
PADDING-TOP: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 7px; -webkit-border-radius: 7px
}
.style1 {color: #0000FF}

#content {  BORDER-BOTTOM: #ccc 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #ccc 1px solid; PADDING-  
BOTTOM: 12px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #fff; MARGIN: 0px auto; PADDING-LEFT: 20px; WIDTH: 
350px; PADDING-RIGHT: 20px; BORDER-TOP: #ccc 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #ccc 1px solid; 
PADDING-TOP: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 7px; -webkit-border-radius: 7px
}
.style3 {color: #0000FF; font-weight: bold; }
.style5 {
color: #0000FF;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
.style7 {color: #0000FF; font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.style8 {font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p><img src="./images/header.JPG" width="1266" height="127" alt="header" /></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="content">
<h1 class="style1">Login Form:</h1>
<form method="post" action="Login.php">
<p>
<label style="DISPLAY: block"><span class="style3">Email:</span></label>
<input class="text" 
name="username" />
</p>
<p>
<label style="DISPLAY: block"><span class="style3">Password:</span></label>
<input class="text" 
type="password" name="password" />
'</p>
<p><a href="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7106563/r-ednalan/login_form.html#">Forgot 
password?</a></p>
<p>
<button class="ptour_crtbtn" name="login" type="submit"><span    
class="style1"><strong>Talk</strong></span><strong>i</strong>n</button>
</p>
<pre><span class="style5">OR</span><span class="style8"><script 
src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script><script>
 FB.init({ 
    appId:'XXXXX', 
    cookie:true, 
    status:true, 
    xfbml:true 
 });
  </script></span>

  <fb:login-button onlogin="alert('Authenticated!');"><div align="left">Login with   
  Facebook</div></fb:login-button></p>

  </p>
  </pre>
  </form>



  </body>
  </html>
```